# How to open new Form from Dialog Result | C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using dialog result in OnChanged(), (FileSystemWatcher) as below :

```
if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    new Form2().Show();      
}
```

But when i click on Yes button, the new form opened as hanged(not responding), please advise.

Comment: Can you show some more code over here.

Comment: Don't do this. Ever. You could set the [FileSystemWatcher.SynchronizingObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher.synchronizingobject), but you never ever block a FSW handler this way. Ever. Move that code somewhere else (a different routine invoked on the UI Thread, understanding that you may flood it with modal Windows).

Comment: Thanks , resolved by doing new Form2().ShowDialog();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
 {
     new Form2().ShowDialog();
 }`

Answer (score 0):

It's done like this:

```
var frm = new Form2()
if (frm.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.Yes)
{
 //write your code here
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For OnChange , you must invoke any GUI as follows :

```
Form2 frm=new Form2;
    frm.Show();
    frm.Hide();
     if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
     {
    // For calling a GUI For inside thread On FileSystemWatcher using Invoke

    frm.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
    frm.Show();
     });
```

Comment: Add some context by explaining how your answer solve the problem in question in addition to comments inline with the code.